# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, foreach, github-api

I am trying to create a program that will write a .js file that will embed a GitHub repository into a .html file.

Everything involving the program is fine, but the actual JavaScript gives this error:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`

I originally wrote this code into a HTML file and it partly worked, but when my program writes it, it doesn't work.

Here the code that my program writes:

```
window.onload = apifunc();
async function apifunc() {
  const url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/piccolowen/noice';
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const result = await response.json();
  const apiresult = document.getElementById('results');
  console.log('api++ system working...')
  console.log('api++ system by Piccolowen https://github.com/Piccolowen')
  console.log('api++ result:');
  console.log(result);
  if (result === null) {
    console.log('result is null')
  } else {
    result.items.forEach(i => {
      const title = document.createElement('a')
      title.href = i.html_url
      title.className = 'classname'
      title.textContent = i.name
      apiresult.appendChild(title)
    })
  }
}
```

It is badly formatted because that is how my program writes it.

When I `console.log(result)` it gives me the contents of this page: https://api.github.com/repos/piccolowen/noice like it is supposed to.

I did add a if statement checking to see if `result` was `null`, but that fixed nothing.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you verify the shape of your response? That error implies that there is no `items` property in your response. If you response is an array, you should do `result.forEach`.

Comment: Please log the results value and check if `items` property is there or not.

Comment: `window.onload = apifunc();` <-- wrong .... You assign what the method returns to the onload handler. You are not calling it onload. It should be `window.onload = apifunc` And in an ideal world, you define the method before you use/reference it.

Comment: Also `apifunc()` is async so it should have been resolved before called.

Comment: There is no `items` property in that JSON. In fact, there are no arrays at all so nothing is a candidate for `.forEach()`